# How can I see how many deleted comments a user has?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I can see when I flagged a comment, but there is no way to tell how many comments have been deleted - ideally grouped by self-deletion or flagging.
I understand that ignorance is bliss, but maybe some less precise value could be indicated. That is 0, 1-3 etc. And updated every week/month to avoid any kind of escalation.

Here are some questions I would like the answer of:

- Have my comments been deleted for moderation (of course with a delay to avoid any "fast reactions"
- Does this user know about the feature of self-deleting comments?

Comment: Do you mean for a specific user (as your title implies)? Why would you want to know that?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi To start with, user:me would be fine

Comment: Since there is no way to determine if a comment was deleted because it became obsolete or if it was for moderation reasons I don't see how seeing deleted count would be helpful.

Comment: Heh :) Actually I think `user:me` may be the only reasonable use case. Digging further looks pretty intrusive to me (a counter does not but would not have much meaning). You can always become a moderator, and then you will understand why you *don't* want such a feature -- the noise alone is most probably terrifying.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I do not want to see the comments, it is rather the indication of behavior that interests me.

Comment: Personally, I hope not:)

Answer (score 14):

Option 1:

1. Become a moderator, or employee of SE with moderator access to the site.
2. Visit every single post that you have any activity on and look through them for deleted comments of yours.
3. count.

Option 2:

1. Become a developer of SE with access to the SO database.
2. Write a query to count deleted comments you've posted.

Option 3:

1. Beg someone else to perform options 1 or 2 on your behalf.

Option 4:

1. Delete your account.
2. The number of deleted comments for your account is now 0.

Option 5:

1. Propose a feature request to have this information displayed on your profile.
2. Use one of the other options when the feature request inevitability gets rejected or just ignored.